# How to apply the camera calibration to transform 2D points in image into bearing vectors?

Tags: c++, matrix, computer-vision, geometry

I am trying to find out Camera absolute Rotation and Translation by using 2D-3D points correspondences using EPNP algorithm OpenGV(not OpenCV). But my problem is I have 2D and 3D points but it requires Bearing Vector of the point if you look at the Test code for the algorithm of Absolute Pose finding on the repository. You will find its generating random 3D points and by following code its generating the Bearing Vector of the point in camera reference frame using Rotation and Translation. Please check the following code.

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < (size_t) gt.cols(); i++ )
    gt.col(i) = generateRandomPoint( maxDepth, minDepth );

  //create the 2D3D-correspondences by looping through the cameras
  size_t numberCams = camOffsets.size();
  size_t camCorrespondence = 0;

  for( size_t i = 0; i < (size_t) gt.cols(); i++ )
  {
    //get the camera transformation
    translation_t camOffset = camOffsets[camCorrespondence];
    rotation_t camRotation = camRotations[camCorrespondence];

    //store the point
    points.push_back(gt.col(i));

    //project the point into the viewpoint frame
    point_t bodyPoint = rotation.transpose()*(gt.col(i) - position);

    //project the point into the camera frame
    bearingVectors.push_back(camRotation.transpose()*(bodyPoint - camOffset));

    //normalize the bearing-vector to 1
    bearingVectors[i] = bearingVectors[i] / bearingVectors[i].norm();

    //add noise
    if( noise > 0.0 )
      bearingVectors[i] = addNoise(noise,bearingVectors[i]);

    //push back the camera correspondence
    camCorrespondences.push_back(camCorrespondence++);
    if(camCorrespondence > (numberCams-1) )
      camCorrespondence = 0;
  }
```

Bearing vectors are inputs/measurements obtained from images. For detail description of Bearing Vector you can check [here](http://laurentkneip.github.io/opengv/page_how_to_use.html).

So I am looking for a way to apply the camera calibration to transform 2D points into bearing vectors.

Comment: if you have 2D and 3D points correspondance, why don't you use a camera model to get the projection matrix ?

Comment: Are you suggesting me to use camera's Intrinsic Matrix?